# Preserve custom URL parameter on more pages

Tags: plugins, php, urls

I created a custom URL parameter for sorting posts by their vote scores. I have a "most voted" link that sends a `?sort=most_voted` URL paramater and using a query posts filter I display posts with most votes.

If for instance I want to display most voted posts in category 5, I'll need a URL like this `?cat=5&sort=most_votes`

How do I preserve/attach the `sort` parameter in the URL when browsing categories (or even by tag name, search, etc)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _"preserve"_ the sort parameter. Do you mean *"How do I parse a URL such that it generates a list of posts on a category page using the desired sort order?"*

Comment: Yes, I want to keep `sort` in the URL when navigating away, in a category.

Comment: Why don't you past the code your using on your template and functions file so we can review the whole thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to intercept the links generated by WordPress and append the query var onto the relevant URLs.

You can do this quite easily with a filter on category URLs with something like...

```
function add_my_query_var( $link ) {
    $link = add_query_arg( 'sort', 'most_voted', $link );
    return $link;
}
add_filter('category_link','add_my_query_var');
```

I also spotted this handy list of filters on [Mike's post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472334/is-there-a-way-to-exclude-domain-from-link-generation-in-wordpress/3474234#3474234), it should cover all the possible URLs you'd want to tweak the query vars for...

```
add_filter('page_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('post_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('term_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('tag_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('category_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('post_type_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('attachment_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('year_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('month_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('day_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('search_link','add_my_query_var');

add_filter('feed_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('post_comments_feed_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('author_feed_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('category_feed_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('taxonomy_feed_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('search_feed_link','add_my_query_var');

add_filter('get_edit_tag_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('get_edit_post_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('get_delete_post_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('get_edit_comment_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('get_edit_bookmark_link','add_my_query_var');

add_filter('index_rel_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('parent_post_rel_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('previous_post_rel_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('next_post_rel_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('start_post_rel_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('end_post_rel_link','add_my_query_var');

add_filter('previous_post_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('next_post_link','add_my_query_var');

add_filter('get_pagenum_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('get_comments_pagenum_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('shortcut_link','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('get_shortlink','add_my_query_var');

add_filter('home_url','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('site_url','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('admin_url','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('includes_url','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('content_url','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('plugins_url','add_my_query_var');

add_filter('network_site_url','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('network_home_url','add_my_query_var');
add_filter('network_admin_url','add_my_query_var');
```

Hope that helps..

Comment: Brilliant answer! Thanks this should put me on the right path :)

Comment: Btw, is it wise to create the functions before defining the filters? I have mine vice-versa

Comment: @wpStudent: It does not matter. The function needs to exist when the hook is executed, not when you assign it. I also do hook-then-function, it makes it easier to follow if you have long functions.

Comment: +1 for what Jan said... :) I tend to place the action prior to the function(FWIW), but when giving an example i don't really fuss about smaller details... ;)

Comment: And if you put the names of the all the hooks into an array you can iterate over them with foreach. If the array is then returned by a function, this is even mor easy for future use.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the [add_query_arg() (Wordpress Function)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg) to add an additional parameter to the query (or also called query-info) part of an URL.

```
$baseUrl = '...'; // the url you want to add your parameter to
$sort = '...'; // the sort parameter you have
$sortUrl = add_query_arg('sort', $sort, $baseUrl);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing!! I wasn't aware of that WP function.