# Preserve custom URL parameter after saving post

Tags: customization, admin

I'm testing different layouts for my admin pages, and the easiest way I found to determine which layout to load is with URL parameters. One of those parameters is "fullscreen=1" which hides the admin menu, for instance. The problem is, whenever I save a post / custom post type by submitting a form, WordPress will redirect me without preserving my parameter, thus breaking my layout by adding back the admin menu...

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured this one out. Turns out I was so focused on filters and actions that I forgot about the basics.

In order to preserve any custom URL parameters after saving a post (via submitting the form) do the following:

Filter your admin URL with a conditional that checks for the parameter you want to preserve ([based on this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4618/preserve-custom-url-parameter-on-more-pages)), like this:

```
add_filter('admin_url','add_fullscreen_param');
function add_fullscreen_param( $link ) {
    if(isset($_REQUEST['fullscreen']) && $_REQUEST['fullscreen'] == '1') {
        $params['fullscreen'] = '1';
    }
    $link = add_query_arg( $params, $link );

    return $link;
}
```

Then, all you have to do is make sure you send that request along with your form, because it will activate the filter above prior to redirecting back to your post / page / custom post type. To do this, simply add a hidden input.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['fullscreen']) && $_REQUEST['fullscreen'] == '1') {  
    echo('<input type="hidden" name="fullscreen" value="1" />');
}
```

So if you access `/wp-admin/post.php?post=100&action=edit&fullscreen=1`, that last parameter will be there after saving the form.

Comment: Thanks saved my bacon! I started to get some odd behaviour (admin CSS thrown out, couldn't get in admin through top bar) with the code as it is. I swapped it round so the new link is within the if statement, which solved matters, I have no idea why! if( _POST['profile_type'] ) {
        $params['profile_type'] = $_POST['profile_type'];
        $link = add_query_arg( $params, $link );
 }
    return $link;